# Set all selects lists by class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several `input type="select"` with  the same class. All with the same option values. I'm iterating through an array and checking if the option value is in it. If it is then I want all those relevant option values to be selected. I tried with this JQuery but it doesn't update the select dropdown with the selected values:

**JS**

```
$(".contacts option").each(function() {
    var x = $(this);
    if($.inArray(x.val(), selected_values)!= -1){
        x.prop('selected', true);
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control contacts" name="publicPermissions" id="publicPermissions" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="share">Share</option>
    <option value="private">Private</option>
    <option value="user">User Config</option>
    <option value="work">Work</option>
</select>
```

I have several of these `selects` how can I update them all so they all have the relevent option values selected?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method. No need to use loop.

```
$(".contacts").val(selected_values);
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/07d9ogaw/)

Answer (score 3):

After you put some values in `selected_values` array, it should work. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4jfgq65e/)